# .delegate question

Tags: jquery

I am using the below code to display a text in a text field which dissappears when you focus on it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.onfocus_rem_txt').each(function(){
   $(this).val($(this).attr('defaultVal'));
   $(this).css({color:'grey'});
  });

  $('.onfocus_rem_txt').focus(function(){
   if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('defaultVal')){
   $(this).val('');
   $(this).css({color:'black'});
   }
  });

  $('.onfocus_rem_txt').blur(function(){
   if ($(this).val() == ''){
   $(this).val($(this).attr('defaultVal'));
   $(this).css({color:'grey'});
   }
  });
});
```

How can I use .delegate in order to use it in every new.php page that I open???

Comment: you could hook it up to the body of the page but thats why they have live()

Answer (score 0):

you can delegate the `.focus` and `.blur` events like so, shouldn't need to iterate with `.each`, just pre-apply the value and text color when you create the `input` element

example: http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/fLnjX/

```
var $container = $('#container');

$container.delegate('.onfocus_rem_txt', {
    'focus': function() {
        var $that = $(this);
        if ($that.val() === $that.attr('defaultVal')) {
            $that.val('').css('color', 'black');
        }
    },
    'blur': function() {
        var $that = $(this);
        if ($that.val() === '') {
            $that.val($that.attr('defaultVal')).css('color', 'grey');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use live in order to use this functionality at multiple places

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.onfocus_rem_txt').each(function(){
     $(this).val($(this).attr('defaultVal'));
     $(this).css({color:'grey'});
  }).live({
     'focus': function(){
       if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('defaultVal')){
         $(this).val('');
         $(this).css({color:'black'});
       },
     'blur': function(){
       if ($(this).val() == ''){
        $(this).val($(this).attr('defaultVal'));
        $(this).css({color:'grey'});
       }

  });
});
```